# Why does the accelerometer run in the Intel XDK emulator, but not on the device?

Tags: android, cordova, accelerometer, intel-xdk

I'm trying to write an application using the Intel XDK that allows you to turn on and off the accelerometer via the phone and log the measurements taken.

It runs as expected in the Intel XDK emulator, but does not run on the device via "testing" or as a built .apk file.

The accelerometer demos from the XDK program run fine on my test devices, so I'm pretty sure it isn't a hardware problem on my devices. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

While this may be a simple question, is there a location that you have to enable the accelerometer for the test or build? I know the build options include adding / not adding camera, geolocation, contacts, etc., but I haven't seen anything for the accelerometer.  I'm using the default "Android build" and have the following scripts loaded in my index.html file (this is in script tags right below the onDeviceReady() function):

```
 js/appframework.ui.min.js"
 script src="intelxdk.js"
 script src="cordova.js"
 script src="js/accelerometer.js" (this is my file that has the JS referenced below.  The "o)
```

What I'm wanting to do is have a "start recording acceleration" button and a "stop recording acceleration" button (vs the examples that have the accelerometer running continually). The only way I was able to get the app to successfully to run, stop and then start again is to move the `intel.xdk.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onsuccess, options);` from the onDeviceReady() function to a function below called "startWatch()". Do you have to have the device-related functions in the onDeviceReady() function to run?

Here's the code:

```
var acc_data = []; // Array containing X,Y,Z accelerometer objects
var watchID = null;

function startWatch() {
    // Start watching the acceleration
    // Update acceleration every .1 seconds
    var options = { frequency: 100, adjustForRotation: true };

    watchID = intel.xdk.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, options);
    var date = new Date();
    track_id = "Arm_Test "+ date;
    onSuccess;

}


// Success - Start watching accelerometer data
function onSuccess(acceleration) {

    acc_data.push(acceleration);

    var element2 = document.getElementById('arm_acc_test');
    element2.innerHTML = track_id;

    var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />' +
    'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />' +
    'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />' +
    'Timestamp: ' + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';

}


// Stop watching the acceleration
function stopWatch() {

    intel.xdk.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);

    window.localStorage.setItem(track_id, JSON.stringify(acc_data));

    var element3 = document.getElementById('arm_acc_test');
    element3.innerHTML = "Test Complete";

    var element4 = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element4.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i=0, len = acc_data.length; i<len; i++) {
        var output = "x: " + acc_data[i]['x'] + "<br>" + "y: " + acc_data[i]['y'] + "<br>" + 
        "z: " + acc_data[i]['z'] + "<br>" + "timestamp: " + acc_data[i]['timestamp'] +
        "<br><br>";
        var element5 = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
        element5.innerHTML += output;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example that I've put together for demo purposes. It will eventually become a sample. It provides a much more thorough treatment of the accelerometer code. You should be able to glean what you need from it:

https://github.com/xmnboy/hello-cordova

You'll find what you need in this file:

https://github.com/xmnboy/hello-cordova/blob/master/www/js/cordova-acc.js

It works properly in the XDK emulator and in apps built for iOS, Android (old, new and Crosswalk) and Win8 Phone as well as in App Preview.

One thing to pay close attention to is when you initialize the accelerometer code, it must occur *after* the device ready event. There is some fancy device ready detection code in this file:

https://github.com/xmnboy/hello-cordova/blob/master/www/js/init-dev.js

that will handle a Cordova device ready, and XDK device ready and running in a regular browser.

Eventually, I'll update this app so it also works with the HTML5 device motion api...

Comment: THANKS!  I'm going through it now & it looks like that will solve the challenge.